# Ajax Call inside event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to execute an AJAX call inside an event handler function for about a day, trying lot of `when()`, `then()` and `done()` stuff and also to set `async: false` but I am still ending up with undefined errors. My code looks like this:

```
$('#id').on('itemMoved', function (event) {
  console.log(event);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "create.php",
    data: event
  });
});
```

I need to pass the event object to create.php to do some server-side stuff. As `console.log(event)` is printing the object correctly, I guess the reason is the asynchronous behaviour of ajax - but have still no idea how to solve it.

**Edit:** First of all, sorry for not making it complete. Lack of knowledge makes it more difficult to decide what is relevant.

`itemMoved` is an event of jQuery UI Widget jxqkanban. It is triggered when a Kanbanitem is dragged and holds information about old and new column and itemdata ([Documentation](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxkanban/index.htm#demos/jqxkanban/kanban-events.htm)). I think AJAX is running before the objects content is completely resolved, causing

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `event` needs to be serialised before sending to the server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — Why JSON and not form encoding?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] and a *clear problem statement*. You said you got "undefined errors" but you haven't said what is undefined. The only part of your code which appears to read anything is when you log the event, and you said that *wasn't* undefined.  `itemMoved` isn't a standard event anyway, what is its value? What does the Network tab in the browser's developer tools show? It should tell you what is in the outgoing POST request. Is it what you expect? If not, how does it differ?

Comment: Simplicity mostly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Trying to serialize it throws error: "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — JSON makes it more complicated. The URL is a PHP URL. PHP doesn't have native decoding into `$_POST` for JSON requests. (Also you shouldn't POST JSON without setting the Content-Type explicitly when you use jQuery Ajax).

Comment: @varunagarwal — Passing an object to `data` in jQuery Ajax **does** serialize it

Comment: Fair enough, I've removed the comment. My main point was that it's very odd to be sending a client-side event object to the server. That, to me, would be a code smell.

Comment: @Quentin it does serialise it, but it's the default serialisation method which is causing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/pm0ebs7L/. Converting it to JSON works, although as you say creates extra steps for the server side logic.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — The OP says converting to JSON throws a circular reference error (and they aren't using a standard event).

Comment: The real solution here is probably "Make your own object and copy the specific data out of the event which you care about into it"

Comment: Ah yeah, they added that comment in response to my original. Either way 1) we need details of what this proprietary event object actually contains 2) this is probably not the best way to achieve what the OP is trying to do anyway

Comment: Sorry for the unclarities, I updated the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Just been having a play in js fiddle link here.

https://jsfiddle.net/WillCodeForBeer/29kqpo58/1/

```
$("#click").click(function(event){    
   console.log(event)    
   data = {};    
   data.timestamp = event.timeStamp
   $.post('/echo/js/?js=hello%20world!', { data : data } );
});
```

I'm not sure what error you are getting but when I tried to only send the event data I was getting a type error. After some reading, it turns out you cannot be sent the event object as
 it contains HTML as it will reference the event target.

I would suggest something similar to the above code and extract the data you need out of the event object into another data object and post that.

NB. The post does not complete due to the url being a fake url. The triggering event is also different but the concept is the same.

let me know how you get on.

Comment: I added more details about the error to the initial post. Sorry for the confusion and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is fiddle that maybe can be useful to you:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wy12mk0f/3/)

```
$('#id').on('click', function (event) {
    $.post( "https://httpbin.org/post", event).
    done(function( data ) {
       console.log( "Data Loaded: " + data );
       $( "#results" ).append( "Origin: "+ data.origin );
  });                    
});
```

In Ajax, and in javascript, in general, is essential the concept of callback.
So in the example above the function inside done is executed only when the server responds.